# Page redirection in PHP does not work, when clicking on button

Tags: php, redirect

Can someone help me please, to find out why redirection to another page doesn't work?

```
if( !empty($data['email-address']) && is_email($data['email-address']) ){
    $mail_title = tourmaster_get_option('general', 'enquiry-mail-title','');
    $mail_content = get_post_meta($data['tour-id'], 'tourmaster-enquiry-form-mail-content-customer', true);
    if( empty($mail_content) ){
        $mail_content = tourmaster_get_option('general', 'enquiry-mail-content','');
    }
    $mail_title = tourmaster_set_enquiry_data($mail_title, $data);
    $mail_content = tourmaster_set_enquiry_data($mail_content, $data);
    if( !empty($mail_title) && !empty($mail_content) ){
        tourmaster_mail(array(
            'recipient' => $data['email-address'],
            'title' => $mail_title,
            'message' => tourmaster_mail_content($mail_content)
        ));
    }

    $ret = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => esc_html__('Your enquiry has been sent. Thank you!', 'tourmaster')
    );

    
    header('Location: https://mypage.com/page/', true, 301);
    exit();
}
```

After action is triggered, page is not redirecting but, but in developer tools you can see that redirection has been initialized:

[image]

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you output anything to the browser prior to the redirect? That would stop it. If you enable error reporting, does it say anything about "headers already sent"?

Comment: AJAX requests won't redirect the main document!